# Gorm: How to store a struct in a field

Tags: go, struct, blockchain, hedera-hashgraph

I am trying to save an hederea contract ID of type *hedera.ContractID into a Gorm field but i get the error "*invalid field found for struct github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-go/v2.AccountID's field AliasKey: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer interface*"

package contract

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/.../scanner/controllers/blockchain"
    database "github.com/.../scanner/db"
    model "github.com/.../scanner/models"
    "github.com/rs/xid"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func DeployContract() *gorm.DB {

    //connect to database
    db, err := database.ConnectToDB()

    //if db connection fails
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //init model
    var modelContract model.Contract

    //check if a contract has been deployed
    if err := db.First(&modelContract); err.Error != nil {
        //no deployment found

        //Migrate the schema
        db.AutoMigrate(&model.Contract{})

        //deploy contract
        contract, _ := blockchain.DeployContract()

        //create record

        // generate random id
        id := xid.New()

        // Create
        db.Create(&model.Contract{
            Id:            id.String(),
            ContractId:    contract.Receipt.ContractID,
            GasUsed:       contract.CallResult.GasUsed,
            TransactionId: fmt.Sprint(contract.TransactionID),
            Timestamp:     contract.ConsensusTimestamp,
            ChargeFee:     fmt.Sprint(contract.TransactionFee),
            PayerAccount:  fmt.Sprint(contract.TransactionID.AccountID),
            Status:        fmt.Sprint(contract.Receipt.Status),
        })

    }

    return db
}
```

**Gorm Model**

```
package models

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-go/v2"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Contract struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id            string
    ContractId    *hedera.ContractID
    GasUsed       uint64
    TransactionId string
    Timestamp     time.Time
    ChargeFee     string
    PayerAccount  string
    Status        string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [custom data types](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Implements-Customized-Data-Type), you need to specify how the value will be stored and retrieved from your database. This is done by implementing the `Scanner` and `Valuer` interfaces.

However, since `hedera.ContractID` is defined in another package, you will need to create your own `ContractID` and implement these interfaces. Something like this:

```
type ContractID hedera.ContractID

type Contract struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id            string
    ContractId    *ContractID
    GasUsed       uint64
    TransactionId string
    Timestamp     time.Time
    ChargeFee     string
    PayerAccount  string
    Status        string
}     

func (c *ContractID) Scan(value interface{}) error {
  bytes, ok := value.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Failed to unmarshal ContractID value:", value))
  }

  return json.Unmarshal(bytes, c)
}

func (c ContractID) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  return json.Marshal(c)
}
```

Additionally, cast `hedera.ContractID` into `model.ContractID` wherever it is used. For example:

```
    cID := model.ContractID(*contract.Receipt.ContractID)

    // Create
    db.Create(&model.Contract{
        Id:            id.String(),
        ContractId:    &cID,
        GasUsed:       contract.CallResult.GasUsed,
        TransactionId: fmt.Sprint(contract.TransactionID),
        Timestamp:     contract.ConsensusTimestamp,
        ChargeFee:     fmt.Sprint(contract.TransactionFee),
        PayerAccount:  fmt.Sprint(contract.TransactionID.AccountID),
        Status:        fmt.Sprint(contract.Receipt.Status),
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the message but how can I apply it.

Comment: Add this code to your code (maybe where your `Contract` struct is defined).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still cannot get it to work. This is what I have done https://play.golang.com/p/id4GlSqi0-a

Comment: I updated my code with a custom `ContractID` definition.

Comment: Thanks for the message, the scanner/valuer works but when trying to create a db instance using  db.Create I get an IncompatibleAssign error for ContractId(storing a value of  contract.Receipt.ContractID) as it now has to be of type ContractID hedera.ContractID

Comment: Added more code to the answer, because you need to cast `hedera.ContractID` into `models.ContractID`.

Comment: Is possible to cast the ContractId read from db. back to *hedera.ContractID

Comment: you should be able to do something like `hederaContractID := hedera.ContractID(cID)` where `cID` is of type `model.ContractID`.

Comment: A big thank you, it worked well. I ended up doing hederaContractID := hedera.ContractID(*cID); thanks again.